# Add a value to all entries of a vector without a loop

Tags: algorithm, c++11, stl, functional-programming

I am trying to add a scalar value to all entries of the vector without a loop. The most obvious way is to use a loop.

```
for ( auto it = a.begin(); it != a.end(); ++it )
{
   *it += scalar;
}
```

I want to use `algorithm` and `functional` to do this and one other way I figured out was to do something like this:

```
std::transform( a.begin(), a.end(), a.begin(), std::bind2nd( std::plus< int > (), scalar ) );
```

While reading through the documentation, I learnt that `bind2nd` is deprecated in C++11.

1. What is the best way to do this without using deprecated features of C++11?
2. Apart from a few less lines of code, do I get any performance advantage by using `std::transform` instead of using a loop?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no way to do it that doesn't ultimately come down to a loop under the hood, but you could use `std::for_each` and a lambda (you tagged the question C++11):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>

int main() {
    std::vector<int> ints { 10, 12, 20, 22 };
    std::for_each(ints.begin(), ints.end(), [](int& i) { i += 5; });
    std::cout << "ints: ";
    for (auto& i : ints)
        std::cout << i << " ";
    std::cout << "\n";
    return 0;
}
```

Live demo: http://ideone.com/CmQ7ec

Here's the `std::transform` equivalent:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>

int main() {
    std::vector<int> ints { 10, 12, 20, 22 };
    std::transform(ints.begin(), ints.end(), ints.begin(), [](int i) { return i+5; });
    std::cout << "ints: ";
    for (auto& i : ints)
        std::cout << i << " ";
    std::cout << "\n";
    return 0;
}
```

http://ideone.com/F8TgvI

The difference:

```
    std::for_each(ints.begin(), ints.end(), [](int& i) { i += 5; });
```

vs

```
    std::transform(ints.begin(), ints.end(), ints.begin(), [](int i) { return i+5; });
```

Comment: Output of a vector can also be done without looping: `for_each(ints.begin(), ints.end(), [](int i) { cout << i << " "; });`. However, use of transform et al and lambda's tends to obfuscate code IMO, too much symbol noise. If the language allowed `std::transform(ints, i := cout << i << " ")` or similar, then it would be worth using in production.

Answer (score 0):

First std::bind1st, and bind2nd, are replaced with std::bind.  See below.  I am using the new std::bind syntax with the placeholders.  I'm also storing the results in another container using a std::back_inserter.

```
using namespace std::bind::placeholders::_1; 
std::vector<int> result;
std::transform(ints.begin(), ints.end(), std::bind(std::plus<>, _1, 5), std::back_inserter(result));
```

Regarding your second question, it is considered preferred c++ style to prefer algorithms over hand written loops.  I'd recommend reading Scott Meyers [Effective STL](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201749629) Item 43, "Prefer Algorithm calls to hand written loops".  Their is also a discussion in this article on [DrDobbs](http://www.drdobbs.com/stl-algorithms-vs-hand-written-loops/184401446).

Comment: <rant>Nothing against your solution, but I have to opinionate that unfortunately, I find the officially recommended style makes code harder to read and harder to write, itself a source of errors. The common excuse  "you get used to it" is unfortunate and not one I can subscribe to. When transform, bind, inserters etc *can* be combined to solve a problem, the solution always looks to me overly verbose, contrived and unnatural. Beyond the coolness of seeing if a solution *can* be written using these constructs, they remain of academic interest.</rant>

Comment: @Schollii From a style perspective, I think thats valid criticism, but it applies to most of the STL.  The STL lends itself to a very templated, functional style of programming.  Its not really object oriented and so for many developers its unsettling.  You defiantly want to lean towards readability and the new range based forloops may be easier to read for the faint of heart.

Personally I've embraced functional programming in C++ and Python.  Here, we end up with a one liner to define the transform.  In Python this would be a list comprehension :)